# Existing instance variable 'PadControllerDelegate' for property ' PadControllerDelegate' with assign attribute must be _unsafe_unretained

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

```
@interface wisepadViewController : UIViewController <PadControllerDelegate> {
@private
    id<PadControllerDelegate> PadControllerDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<PadControllerDelegate> PadControllerDelegate;
```

now in .m file i made

```
@implementation wisepadViewController


@synthesize PadControllerDelegate;
```

How to fix it , unable to do .where is the issue.

Comment: You seem to be using a very outdate tutorial. Get rid of the ivar and the `@synthesize` lines. You just need the `@propery` line. And change `assign` to `weak` (assuming you are using ARC). Delegate properties are almost always `weak` (instead of `strong`) to avoid reference cycles. Never use `assign` for object references unless you have a good reason (and fully understand the risks).

Comment: FYI - standard naming conventions state that class names begin with uppercase letters. Variable and method names begin with lowercase letters.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, weak) id<PadControllerDelegate>  i made change here .but still error.must be _weak error

Comment: Which line exactly is giving that error?

Comment: @private
    id<PadControllerDelegate> PadControllerDelegate; this line
}

Comment: I stated that you should delete those lines. You don't need an explicit ivar anymore when declaring a property.

Comment: aferter deleting that line . i am getting this error  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
      -[AE1_CommandGenerator resetWavResultWithNewLength:] in libWisePadAPI-2.8.0.a(AE1_CommandGenerator.o)
      -[AE1_CommandGenerator GenerateTone_Command:wavLength:Mode:] in libWisePadAPI-2.8.0.a(AE1_CommandGenerator.o)
      -[AE1_CommandGenerator Clear] in libWisePadAPI-2.8.0.a(AE1_CommandGenerator.o)
      -[AE1_DecoderController dealloc] in libWisePadAPI-2.8.0.a(AE1_DecoderController.o)

Comment: @rmaddy can you tell me why this error is coming how can i fix it,i am third party library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86537/discussion-between-jace-and-rmaddy).

Comment: That nothing to do with the code in your question. That's a whole other issue. The one posted about is now fixed.

Comment: where i need to check about that issue , i am unable to solve and check also@rmaddy